# Keep Baldarov alive in Warsong for Sega Genesis

Tags: warsong

This is something that has always bothered me since I was a kid.  On the back cover of the game Warsong for the Sega Genesis there is a screen that shows the player having all items and it shows that Baldarov is alive.  My question is how is it possible to have him alive at the end of the game, iirc he dies at the end of level 5.

Comment: The only explanation I've seen is that it was a debug mode. Although it could also be to remove spoilers from the back of the box.

Comment: hmm I'd be interested in that story if you have the link

Comment: I wish I could remember where I read it.

Answer (score 1):

Since i dont have the game i cannot verify my theory, but anyways here goes :

There is a cheat called **Level select** which allows you to change level, which goes like this:

```
Move cursor to square (2,2), press and hold C/B.
```

According to these sources, it can be either button B or C.

*Sources*

http://www.gamewinners.com/GEN/Warsong.htm

http://www.gamesurge.com/strategies/Genesis/Walkthroughs-P/Warsong.shtml

---

Finally if you want all items use this [trick](http://www.gamewinners.com/GEN/Warsong.htm) :

> Hold Up/Left + A + B for about twelve seconds at the soldier
>   purchasing screen. You will lose all your money and the music will
>   change, but you will get all the items, except for the Warsong.
>   However, you will get the Dragon Slayer (+5 Attack and +3 Defense).

Comment: He seems to just outright disappear if you skip the levels in this fashion.